# password protected exe file

Tags: passwords, password-protection, copy-protection

I need a tool that can create password for any exe files (modify the file) and in the same time allow me to run this exe using a parameter with the correct the password so the exe run directly.

For example: if the password is "123" and then I created a shortcut with parameter like "protected_file.exe /123" the exe run without password prompt

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a self contained archive of the EXE which is password protected. Most archive formats support some sort of password protection and self contained archives. This method isn't very secure though because it can eventually be cracked using brute force if someone is determined.

Comment: I can not use archives after extracting user can copy the original file.

Comment: That is going to be true of any running EXE. The file path is even handy to find in proc exp. Also, you can clean it up by also including a batch file and running that first after extraction.

Comment: I need something like this tool http://www.freeexelock.com but allow to run exe with password as a parameter

Comment: Pretty much any password scheme can eventually be cracked using brute force if the attacker is determined. The fact that the OP wants to put the password in plaintext in a shortcut is probably a bigger vulnerability.

Comment: This is just an example I will call the exe from another app I will make with arguments